# Encode string for URI

Tags: javascript

How do I encode string for URI, for example `Capitan's Hat ->  Capitan%27s+Hat` or `Сhristmas Hat -> %D0%A1hristmas+Hat`

I tried, several methods `encodeURIComponent(), encodeURI()`, but nothing brings close enough to what I need. Any idea how it is being encoded?

Escape() does bring relatively close result for capitan's hat, but then completely off for christmas hat.

EDIT:

As Thomas said, encodeURIComponent does the job, but how achieve replacing encoded characters, back to characters? As in example `Сhristmas Hat -> "%D0%A1hristmas+Night"`

I know replace(), targeting each character would work, but is there more universal option?

Comment: For which part of the URI? For usage in the query string, `encodeURIComponent` is doing the right thing.

Comment: Seems you are right, encodeURIComponent does the right job. But how do I replace all encoded characters, back to characters? But only characters, as in example ```Сhristmas Hat -> "%D0%A1hristmas+Night" ```

I know replace(), targeting each character would work, but is there any universal option?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('Capitan\'s Hat'))`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const encode = str => new URLSearchParams([['', str]]).toString().slice(1)
const decode = str => new URLSearchParams('=' + str).get('')

console.log(encode('Сhristmas Hat'))
console.log(decode('%D0%A1hristmas+Hat'))
```

Explanation: the `URLSearchParams` constructor can take either an array of key/value pairs (`[['key', 'value']]`) or a query string (`'key=value'`). Calling `get` on a `URLSearchParams` instance retrieves the unencoded value of that key; meanwhile, calling `toString` gives the full string of URL-encoded key/value pairs. In this case, we use empty string `''` as the key, because the key isn't important.

The algorithm for URL encoding query parameters is similar to that of `encodeURIComponent`, but it also replaces spaces with `+`.